# What does "in the shuffle marketing wise" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Part of the reason that he wants an investor is to take the company’s marketing up a notch. “We kind of got lost **in the shuffle marketing wise**,” he said."

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/elizabethmacbride/2017/12/31/a-big-wave-surfer-takes-to-entrepreneurship-building-a-20-million-mattress-company/#2232577b43e5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "lost in the shuffle" is an idiomatic expression that means that something is not getting the attention it deserves.  In this instance, the company is not getting the attention it deserves.  As for the "marketing wise" part, I disagree with the author of this article insofar as I believe he forgot to put a hyphen to connect the two words: ***marketing-wise*** is how I would have written it had I been the author of this article.  The reason for this is that both words are nouns and they're acting as though they were one adverb.

> **Marketing: Definition No. 2:** The strategic functions involved in identifying and appealing to particular groups of consumers, often
>   including activities such as advertising, branding, pricing, and
>   sales. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/marketing.
>
> **Wise: Lemma 2:** Method or manner of doing; way. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wise

In essence, the author is saying that the company is not getting the attention it deserves by way of marketing.

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: The construction also avoids acceptance of responsibility, like the infamous passive "Mistakes were made".  It is a way of saying, without saying, "We overlooked something" or "We did a damn poor job of marketing".